# Django filter using time lookup doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, django

I want to filter the objects according to time only, regardless of the date part. Django has the *time* lookup for datetime fields, but when I use it the value is converted to the current timezone before filtering is done (this is mentioned on the official Django doc).

For example, I have these sample records on PostgreSQL db (these are all in UTC):

| name | datetime |
| --- | --- |
| entry1 | 2021-04-03 11:00:00 |
| entry2 | 2021-05-05 12:00:00 |
| entry3 | 2021-05-06 12:00:00 |
| entry4 | 2021-06-06 14:00:00 |

And with this model I want to get the all objects that have the *datetime* starting from *12:00* onwards, I use the query with the *time* lookup (and considering that *USE_TZ=True*):

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()

>>> Entry.objects.filter(datetime__time_gte=datetime.time(12, 0))
```

I am expecting that the output would return the objects *entry2*, *entry3* and *entry4*, but the actual response only returned *entry4*, which is +2 hours the filter value, which is also the same as local timezone I have, which follows what was explained by the doc. This is the problem I've been experiencing, and so far I don't have any way over it.

How can I filter the objects according to time only, without being affected by time lookups conversion i.e. conserve the filter value?

Comment: If I understand your query correctly you need to query time on a `DateTimeField`. You might wanna take a look at [`TimeField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#timefield)

Comment: @VishalSingh You're suggesting that I change field type from a DateTimeField to a TimeField right?

Comment: If you don't need to search on basis of date then replace it otherwise add another field.

Comment: I still need to store and search on the date as well as datetime basis. I think the idea of separating the date and time on different fields will create unnecessary overhead e.g. to store the date and time from the datetime object you need to add some logic to separate them first everytime

Comment: @JihadTalic what is the value of `TIME_ZONE` in your settings?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It's set to `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'`